# How can I make an object slide down indefinetly and not bounce back up when it hits the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a group of images I'm animating to slide down. I want them to restart at the top of the screen when they hit the bottom instead of bouncing back up then back down. How can I achieve this?

CSS

```
    .box-buttons { 
      width:70%;height:750px;background-color:grey;float:left;margin: 30px 3%;
      border: 1px solid black;overflow:hidden
    }

    .object {
      animation: slide 9s linear infinite;
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }
    
    @keyframes slide {
      0%, 100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
      }
      50% {
        transform: translateY(500px);
      }
    }
```

html

```
        <div class="box-buttons"><div class="object">
              <img class=spam-button-size src=buttons/cs3.gif><img class=spam-button-size src=buttons/opposingforce.gif> <img class=spam-button-size src=buttons/snakes.gif><img class=spam-button-size src=buttons/sprunk.gif><img class=spam-button-size src=buttons/web3.gif><img class=spam-button-size src=buttons/piracy.gif><img class=spam-button-size src=buttons/3dfx_banner.gif><img class=spam-button-size src=buttons/linuxnow.gif><img class=spam-button-size src=buttons/hack.gif><img class=spam-button-size src=buttons/china2.gif><img class=spam-button-size src=buttons2/thoughtcrimes.png><img class=spam-button-size src=buttons2/28.gif><img class=spam-button-size src=buttons2/anime.jpeg><img class=spam-button-size src=buttons2/anime2.gif>
        </div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVddd.png

Comment: You need to change the 0%, 100% to 0% and 50% to 100% check this https://jsfiddle.net/aussieworz83/zt7e328b/1/

Comment: @ianworsley this works pretty well but do you know how I could make it so when the bottom of the image sliding down hits the bottom theres a point where half is visible on the top and half is visible on the bottom so it looks more natural

Comment: I dont have your image or html if you could share a little more of your code it would help

Comment: If you know the imgs height something like this would work. https://jsfiddle.net/aussieworz83/zt7e328b/8/

Comment: Im using a group of images that are all sliding down at the same time, I think my solution is gonna have to be to use two different elements sliding down one after another to give the illusion where you can see the image at the same time, at the bottom and top of the box it's moving in. I'll post the html and a screenshot of the images though.

Comment: You are open to javascript?

Comment: yeah @ianworsley, I only know basic java script though.

Comment: Im not really sure what the best way of doing it would be but maybe using the canvas could be the way to go https://jsfiddle.net/aussieworz83/3u2980jn/66/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the animation css like this should be good.

```
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(500px);
  }
}
```